# How to disable a button when the function returns a specific returncode in Swift

Tags: swift

Assuming I have a ruction which returns Int32:

```
func check() -> Int32 {
   //doing sth
}
```

And a button:

```
@IBAction func mybtn(_ sender: NSButton) {
   //doing sth here of course
}
```

For instance, I want mybtn is disabled WHEN check() function returns 30. Here's how I do it:

```
mybtn.isEnabled = false
while (check() == 30) {
   print("Invalid, don't break this while loop")
}
//If check() != 30, continue

mybtn.isEnabled = true
```

However Xcode returned:

```
Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'
```

So my question is: How to disable a button when the function returns a specific returncode? In case my code above is right, what should I edit it so that the error goes away? Please help me with this. Thank you so much

Comment: Use the property observer or the Combine guy.

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: Anybody pls help me

Comment: @ElTomato Please explain more detail

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    mybtn.isEnabled = true
    
    while (check() == 30) {
        mybtn.isEnabled = false
    }
}
```

here is References

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618217-isenabled